# SDImageCache - imageFromMemoryCache returns nil

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdwebimage

I'm using the latest version of SDWebImage (SDImageCache), and saving image by code

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] storeImage:image forKey:@"1"];
```

and I'm sure the image have been saved successfully, because I've checked my app folder, there is an image existing in it.

and I'm using

```
UIImage *image = [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] imageFromMemoryCacheForKey:@"1"];
```

to read my image out, but the image object returns nil. 
What could the problem be? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that the image object is not nil when you are storing it ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's NOT nil. Because I can also view my images in App folder.

Comment: Ok, check with the `- (void)queryDiskCacheForKey:(NSString *)key done:(void (^)(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType))doneBlock` method

Comment: Yes, it works, it found the image, but when I set imageView.image = image;

Comment: Doesn't show anything, weired, keep working now..

Comment: Can I add it as my answer ?

Comment: Because of you, I created a SDWebImage sample project and checked it's working. +1 for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use:

```
- (void)storeImage:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key
```

The image is also saved in the disk cache.

The implementation is something like:

```
- (void)storeImage:(UIImage *)image forKey:(NSString *)key
{
    [self storeImage:image imageData:nil forKey:key toDisk:YES];
}
```

So if you need to retreive the image from disk, you can use the following method instead:

```
- (void)queryDiskCacheForKey:(NSString *)key done:(void (^)(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType))doneBlock;
```

The default disk cache type will be `SDImageCacheTypeNone`, so if you need to specify cache type use the `SDImageCacheType` enum.

```
enum SDImageCacheType
{
    /**
* The image wasn't available the SDWebImage caches, but was downloaded from the web.
*/
    SDImageCacheTypeNone = 0,
    /**
* The image was obtained from the disk cache.
*/
    SDImageCacheTypeDisk,
    /**
* The image was obtained from the disk cache.
*/
    SDImageCacheTypeMemory
};
```

Hope, it'll help you.